# How to get list item index when user clicks on the button which is in list item in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-8

I've list box in my application.
Below is the screen shot.

[image]

**When user clicks on the list item, then i'm displaying detailed page.
It is handling in below selection changed listener.**

```
private void companiesList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
            //get the selected item from list
            Company selectedItem = (Company)e.AddedItems[0];

     Uri uri = new Uri("/CompanyDetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            //navigate to target page
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);

            FrameworkElement root = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
            root.DataContext = selectedItem;
}
}
```

Upto this it is fine.

**Now when the user clicks on the Delete button which is on the item,
then i've to delete that item from the list.**

```
private void Del_Btn_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the Corresponding item from list i.e. On which delete button is placed.
    //Delete saved company from the database   


    }
```

I'm unable to get that particular list item index on which the delete button is placed.
Ho could I get.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you make selectedItem into a global variable.. then use that to reference the item selected in the delete button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the button by casting the `sender` parameter. From there, you can retrieve the company by casting the DataContext property:

```
private void Del_Btn_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;

    var company = (Company)button.DataContext;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the company after casting. Now I want to remove that item from the list and the list should update immediately. How can I?

Comment: you can directly remove that company item using list.remove(item) method of list(just make sure if you are using list thenyou have implemented inotifypropertychanged on it else convert it into observable collection.

Answer (score 0):

do get the index of the listbox you can direct set the property

SelectedIndex = {Binding asd,Mode=TwoWay}

then in viewmodel

make a property

```
private int _asd;
public int asd
{
get
{
return _asd;
}
set
{
_asd= value;
}
}
```

by this you will get the index of selected item ...
hopes it might help ..